# Rails - redirection problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, redirect

There is many users available in my project. Each user have different home page. And also i have a default home page. My actual code is here..

```
requested_url = "/limited/username"  #It is constantly changing.  
redirect_to(requested_url || :action => "index", :controller => "demo")
```

So, it redirect the page like this `http://localhost:3000/demo/index?%2Flimited=username`. But, actually i need the redirected url like this `http://localhost:3000/limited/username`.

If the `requested_url` is empty then, it redirects correctly. (`http://localhost:3000/demo/index`). But, if its not empty then, it redirects wrongly.

Please tell me what is the problem here?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`||` has higher operator precedence than `=>`, so your redirect call is interpreted as

```
redirect_to( (requested_url || :action) => "index", :controller => "demo")
```

Try this instead:

```
redirect_to( requested_url || {:action => "index", :controller => "demo"})
```

Comment: demo controller is not a common controller. "demo/index" and "/limited/username" both are separated. Sorry!. I don't like to use the if statement. I slightly modified my code like this redirect_to(requested_url || "demo/index"). Now, My problem is solved. Thank you for remembering the operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I'm not privy to the exact details of what you're trying to do here, but you might be able to do something like this:

```
before_filter :redirect_to_requested_url, :if => :requested_url_supplied?

def redirect_to_requested_url
  redirect_to ... get requested url somehow ...
end
```